# Is it possible to create a 4-16 decoder using five 2-4 decoders without enable inputs?

Tags: decoder

So that the outputs represent a 4-input truth table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can make a 3-8 decoder out of 4 2-4 decoders.

ETA:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2friMga.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So I was wrong, and it takes 5. My bad.